# VBA cannot find specific dll

Tags: vba, dll

I am trying to link a dll to a vba project and I am going nut 'cause it fails to find it even if I am 100% sure of the path (I pasted 100 times the path from the exact position).

I called

```
Private Declare Function IMB_connect _
    Lib "C:\Users\Andrea.GIORDANO\Desktop\API\bin_dynamic\API.dll" _
                    (ByVal n As String) As Long
```

But it continues to return me an error 53: File not found.

I don't get what would be the problem that seems so silly... 
I tried with all kind of slashes '\', '\', '/', '//': no success.

FYI I linked the same exact dll within a c++ project and in that case worked well so I believe the dll itself is fine...

Comment: I believe you are missing some of the dependencies of the dll. Why this works from c++? You probably have a different working directory .

Comment: Just to be sure I have hardcoded the same path. And it works.. How can I look for and explicit dependencies? All those files are in the same dir I suppose.

Comment: The working directory of the exe is where windows is looking by default  for dependencies.. Use Dependency Walker to check other dll dependencies .

Comment: I noticed that placing the libs in System32 folder it runs perfectly. Which can be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Your dll is probably dependent on other dlls. You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) to get the full list of the dependent dlls.
The dependent dlls must be in one of the following (from [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications)):

> 1. The directory from which the application loaded.
> 2. The system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the
>      path of this directory.
> 3. The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the
>      path of this directory, but it is searched.
> 4. The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get
>      the path of this directory.
> 5. The current directory.
> 6. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable.
>      Note that this does not include the per-application path specified
>      by the App Paths registry key. The App Paths key is not used when
>      computing the DLL search path.

If you are running a VBA project, probably `Excel.exe` is loading your code. This means the dependent dlls of your `API.dll` must be in one of the directories in the quote above.
Please note that placing dlls in the system directory could affect the functionality of other applications in the system. [(read about dll hell)](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/no-end-to-dll-hell/227300037).